# How to get hidden data in popup menu using Selenium which is not shown in HTML code

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get data from this [page](https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/usa/nba/phoenix-suns-milwaukee-bucks-zBYhhpYl/#ah;1;-4.50;0)
. As you can see ,when I click on odds in popup menu, there appears historical odds in previous periods, but I [don't see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSj0Y.png) this odds in html code (only the last coefficient)

How can I get data from popup menu, using selenium?

Comment: are you willing to get the data from the pop which is displayed when we hover the mouse digit?

Comment: Yes .Exactly this hidden data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check with the below lines of code

```
driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/usa/nba/phoenix-suns-milwaukee-bucks-zBYhhpYl/#ah;1;-4.50;0")

digit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='odds-data-table']/div[36]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[3]/div")

action = ActionChains(driver) 

action.move_to_element(digit).perform()

sleep(3)

popUp = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*. [@id='tooltiptext']").get_attribute("innerText")

print(popUp)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helps!  But how did you find this xpath?

Comment: Well I've just debug for the element in the browser :)

Comment: Can you ,please,  attach screen with xpath, because i can't find it in chrome

Comment: @JeanMiklau can you check now I've added the snap of it

Comment: Thanks, but i still don't understand how you get it, because on my browser if i hover and inspect this element i see only this [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DfGdLtAdQPhU6rDNqeRuaIznj8p8o1mB/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Just try to debug the element in the browser under source tab it will help you?